# Complete URL with python, only need a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, url

I have a URL like: https://example.com/dir/name
and I need to find the real URL, which is something like: https://example.com/dir/name-NUMBER

and I don't have that NUMBER, is there any way to check for an existing URL (or various URL that follow the same pattern) and return that as a string?

many thanks!

Comment: 1. You can try looking for a sitemap which has this info; 2. If the site's code is open (eg: on github), you could look for it there; 3. If you know the possible urls (in this case the number of digits the number has), you could try to brute force by iterating over it and using requests and find the sites that exist (200 as the response code).

Comment: I do know the length of the number, 6 to 8 digits, and I do know it's only numbers, bruteforcing could be a viable way.
My idea is that I check all possible vales (loop) until I get a True, meaning i reached the site. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: That is a perfectly viable way to do it. But since it is 6-8 digits, it would take a long time. I would suggest you use some sort of parallelization in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this brute force method.

```
import requests

valid_urls = []
for url in all_possible_urls:
    response = requests.post(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        valid_urls.append(url)
```

Comment: Could you explain the code a little bit?
I inderstand that you create an empty list
I don't understand the syntaxis after that

then I'm familiar with the rest of the code, although I don't know why == 200, but I'm guessing is a code for a operational url

Comment: https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html